# What is an example of proper ideal $M\subset \mathbb C[x,y]$ such that there is no homomorphism $\mathbb C[x,y]/M\to\mathbb C$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

I am stuck in this problem for a while, and the main idea will be important for some exercises, so I really want to know how to find an example like this

> I need an example of an proper ideal, let's say M, of C[x,y] (the ring of the complex polynomials in x and y) such that the quotient C[x,y]/M do not admit a homomorphism f(x,y) -> f(a, b) (for a, b complex numbers) from C[x,y]/M -> C.

Comment: Why do you think such an $M$ exists?

Comment: @Hoot I'm a little lost but I think I will need such an M in a further statement. Anyway, I wish I could construct rationally things like that so I must learn from some examples

Comment: Do you mean you want to fix $a, b$ and then construct an ideal where evaluation at $(a,b)$ doesn't descend to $C[x,y]/\mathfrak{m}$?  Or are you trying to find an $\mathfrak{m}$ where there is *no* pair $a,b$ such that this happens?

Answer (score 3):

Such an ideal does not exist.  The maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[x, y]$ are all of the form $\mathfrak m = (x - a, y - b)$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb C$ (this is the weak Nullstellensatz).  The quotient homomorphism $\mathbb C[x, y] \to \mathbb C[x, y]/\mathfrak m \simeq \mathbb C$ is simply the evaluation map $f(x, y) \mapsto f(a, b)$.

Now if $M$ is any proper ideal then $M$ is contained in some maximal ideal $\mathfrak m = (x - a, y - b)$.  The natural homomorphism $\mathbb C[x, y]/M \to \mathbb C[x, y]/\mathfrak m \simeq \mathbb C$ is of the form $f(x, y) \mapsto f(a, b)$.